# Posting application/x-www-form-urlencoded using spray

Tags: scala, http, spray

I want to "submit a form" through spray like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: hoge.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=myid&password=mypw
```

I know how to define `POST`, `Host` and `Content-Type`.
The thing is how to put the contents (`username=...`) in the request.

Here is my code waiting for the insertion of the contents:

```
//↑boiler plate↑
val pipe = (
  addHeader(Host("hoge.org"))
  ~> addHeader(`Content-Type`(`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`))
  ~> sendReceive.apply
)
pipe(Post("/")) onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println("okpk")
  case Failure(exc) => println(exc)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`FormData`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-httpx/marshalling/#default-marshallers) marshaller:

```
pipe(Post("/", FormData(Seq(
      "username" -> "myid",
      "password" -> "mypw"))
    )) onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println("okpk")
  case Failure(exc) => println(exc)
}
```