# FormData being converted to JSON

Tags: scala, spray, json4s

I'm trying to post to a service using Spray

`var authenticationPipeline: HttpRequest => Future[Authentication] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[Authentication]`

I have a pipeline setup, that is expecting to return a type of Authentication (a case class) and unmarshal this. Pretty straight forward.

When constructing requests, I attempt to use to following pattern.

```
val fD = FormData(Seq(
    "grant_type" -> "authorization_code",
    "code" -> authorisation_code,
    "redirect_uri" -> "http://www.example.com",
    "client_id" -> apiClientId,
    "client_secret" -> apiClientSecretKey
))
```

I'm then sending this like so.

`authenticationPipeline(Post(oauthUrl, fD))`

The issue is that the service I'm posting to is returning an unsupported media type error, and upon further inspection it looks like the http enitity's media/content type is json and the content is a json string.

I've got around this issue by using URLEncode and posting this raw string by manually constructing a HTTP request, the issue is now I'm running into issue with encoding and it's just not very clean code. I guess I'm just unsure why this is happening almost implicitly.

The following links influenced how I set this up but don't mention similar issues, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/JjA2LCLfib8 & [Posting application/x-www-form-urlencoded using spray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928840/posting-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-using-spray)

Any pointers on what I could be doing wrong would be appreciated. Please let me know if I've omitted any essential information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing my code in isolation I was able to determine that one of my imports was bringing in an implicit JSON marshaller. By being more specific with my imports I was able to surmount this problem. Hope this helps someone in the future!